# 14.04 install to 16.04 fail

Tags: 16.04

Please, any help appreciated.

I have downloaded the upgrade from the automatic reminder. My machine is 32bit.

I can open to Log On screen, and then insert password. All is well. Come to the first user screen and i have the 2 desktop icons as per 14.04 that i had saved.i am on line, the date is correct, in fact aĺl the information on top right of screen is as it should be.

Insert password and this is accepted, but now i have a page with only my two desktop items and am unable to progress further.

Right click allows me to open terminal or change desktop background.

I cannot get launcher and am stuck at this point.